# Retorno un entero y me devuelve None'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio que pide reducir un numero hasta que  tenga un solo digito.

```
def solve(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    a = 0
    for num in str(num):
        a += int(num)
    solve(a)

print(solve(942))
```

Cuando retorno me devuelve 'None', no entiendo donde esta el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisando tu código, corriéndolo con una pequeña modificación.
(por favor córrelo en tu PC para que veas los resultados tú mismo)

```
def solve(num):
    print(f'valor que solve recibe {num}')
    if num < 10:
        print(f'dentro del buble {num}')
        return f'retorno {num}'
    a = 0
    print(f'valor de a antes del if {a}')
    for num in str(num):
        print(f'valor de num {num} y a es {a}')
        a += int(num)
    print(f'nuevo valor de a {a}')
    solve(a)

print(solve(942))
```

vas a obtener

```
valor que solve recibe 942
valor de a antes del if 0
valor de num 9 y a es 0
valor de num 4 y a es 9
valor de num 2 y a es 13
nuevo valor de a 15
valor que solve recibe 15
valor de a antes del if 0
valor de num 1 y a es 0
valor de num 5 y a es 1
nuevo valor de a 6
valor que solve recibe 6
dentro del buble 6  < ---------------
None
```

El bucle `for` está sumando cada digito de la variable num, es decir

- Primer ciclo: num=942  el valor de a  es 9+4+2 a=15
- Segundo ciclo: a pasa como argumento, nuevo valor de num=15, así que valor de a es 1+5 a=6
- Tercer ciclo: entra al `if` y continúa pero el retorno dentro del bucle no se ejecuta.

Ahora, si anades `return solve(a)` a la ultima linea:

```py
def solve(num):
    print(f'valor que solve recibe {num}')
    if num < 10:
        print(f'dentro del buble {num}')
        return f'retorno {num}'
    a = 0
    print(f'valor de a antes del if {a}')
    for num in str(num):
        print(f'valor de num {num} y a es {a}')
        a += int(num)
    print(f'nuevo valor de a {a}')
    return solve(a)

print(solve(942))
```

La respuesta es un poco diferente

```py
valor que solve recibe 942
valor de a antes del if 0
valor de num 9 y a es 0
valor de num 4 y a es 9
valor de num 2 y a es 13
nuevo valor de a 15
valor que solve recibe 15
valor de a antes del if 0
valor de num 1 y a es 0
valor de num 5 y a es 1
nuevo valor de a 6
valor que solve recibe 6
dentro del buble 6
retorno 6
```

Básicamente tu recursión no está mal, pero no estas retornando la función como tal, debes retornar la llamada a la misma función, es decir `return solve(a)`, el bucle `if` es tu estrategia de salida y está bien colocar el `return` si se cumple la función, pero no olvides el retorno que llama a la misma función (eso es lo que hace la recursión).

recursión no es un tema fácil y no es fácil ni implementarlo ni entenderlo así que no te desanimes.

Answer (score 0):

Sencillo, necesitas retornar en todas las veces que invocaste tu método de forma recursiva. Si no lo haces lo que retorna cada ejecución final se pierde porque no se propaga en la ejecución que lo invocó :)

```
def solve(num):
    if num < 10:
        return num
    a = 0
    for num in str(num):
        a += int(num)
    return solve(a)

print(solve(942))
```